# Why does Apple use different folder structures for bundle and strings localization?

Tags: ios, internationalization, bundle, application-settings, localizable.strings

I am localizing my app, I found Apple use different folder structures for bundle or strings.

Can anyone tell me why Apple doesn't use the same folder structures for easy of use?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The folder structure for localization *is* the same for the settings bundle and everything else in your app.

The reason why it seems different is because the settings part of an application is put together in something called a "bundle".

**Right click (or control click) on the Settings.bundle in Finder:**

[image]

**You will see a menu option called "Show Package contents".**

[image]

**You should see the localization folders in there.**

[image]

For more information on [packages and bundles see the Apple Developer Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html).

Comment: I made a mistake in my question, I want to talk about folder structures in Xcode, not real file system structures. I knew about real structures because I had localized my app from English.lproj to en.lproj and add other languages locale. I just want to view the same logical group or folder in Xcode for all localization.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: @Moshe Out of topic question: How to edit such a beautiful picture above whitch is fuzzy around and clear some areas?